# White screen shows instead of splash screen --ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen, ionic4

I am working on a project in ionic 4 ,when i try to change the icon and splash screen of my own .i replace my icon with icon.png and splash with splash.png after  `ionic Cordova resources` run. app icon is successfully replaced with my new icon in icon folder and splash screen also replaced with my new screen in splash folder, after build android the icon is changed but the splash screen is not visible at all only a white screen shows for 5-7 sec and then show my app's home page. if anyone know how to solve that please let my know.

Comment: whats in your \platforms\android\app\src\main\res drawable's folder they should contain your splash screen

Answer (score 1):

I remember struggling with that issue as well, it was solved by adding some preferences in the config.xml.

This is in my current (ionic 3) project, hope this helps.

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

**EDIT**

Also make sure you have the cordova splashscreen plugin installed

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen

npm install --save @ionic-native/splash-screen
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i have test this in my app but nothing changes.if you have any other suggestion do let me know . once again thanks